# Why is my url redirect command not working properly?

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have an internal website `http://example/`. I need to redirect all traffic to the new internal site (`http://newexample/`) **except** all content in the following two subfolders:

1. `/Admin/`
2. `/API/Test/`

Here is what I tried:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect Example" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^Admin/.*" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^API/Test/.*" negate="true"/>                       
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://newexample/" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The problem I am having is that it is redirecting everything **including** the content in the two subfolders. I have also tried removing the `negate` attribute which causes no pages to be redirected.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the solution I found in the hopes that it will help someone later. It all had to do with the `<match url="(^$)" />`, and the `pattern` attribute on the `add` elements. Look closely at the very subtle differences:

I changed:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect Example" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^Admin/.*" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^API/Test/.*" negate="true"/>                       
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://newexample/" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

to

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect Example" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(^$)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^Admin$" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^API/Test$.*" negate="true"/>               
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://newexample/" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do some small changes in your rule.

```
<rule name="Redirect Example" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/Admin/.*" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/API/Test/.*" negate="true" />                       
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://newexample/" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
```

[image]